# After deploying React app, to display image; use build or public folder?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am storing images in assets folder in either build or public folder and in my component rendering images based on process.env

```
                    <img
                  alt="Screenshot"
                  src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/${coin.itemId}.png`}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setImgTrue(true);
                    setTempImg(
                      `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/${coin.itemId}.png`
                    );
                  }}
```

if my deployment server is pointing towards build folder, does the process.env.PUBLIC_URL point to the build folder as well?

Comment: Actually, you can't store images into your asset folder after deployment./ But u can use cloudinary.

Comment: whats another way to store images after deployment in reacT?